# convert datetime strings and order by date

Tags: r, sorting, date, posixct

I have a non-trivial issue with the ever-recurring difficulty of getting strings in R denoting a date-time into an object that R understands as such (POSIXct?).

I have a character vector of date-times, which looks like this:

```
 [1] "Thu Apr 19 00:42:24 +0000 2018" "Sat Apr 14 03:08:30 +0000 2018" "Thu Apr 02 12:42:07 +0000 2015"
 [4] "Wed Apr 25 02:24:49 +0000 2018" "Sun Apr 03 00:37:19 +0000 2016" "Fri Apr 11 10:02:42 +0000 2014"
 [7] "Tue Jan 09 13:57:33 +0000 2018" "Wed Apr 13 09:45:05 +0000 2016" "Thu May 18 11:26:10 +0000 2017"
[10] "Thu Oct 05 03:41:32 +0000 2017"
```

My goal is to sort these values so that the most recent date is at the top and the oldest date is at the bottom. As far as I know, this will involve converting these strings to date-time objects, but even this step I haven't gotten to work.

I've tried:

```
lubridate::as_date(dates[1], tz = "UTC", format = NULL)
as.POSIXct(dates[1], tz = "UTC")
```

but I always get the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I presume that I can fix this through specifying the `format` argument, but how exactly do I do this?
Furthermore, once I've converted them (or, if I don't need to convert them, without doing so) - how can I then sort these dates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `+0000` in your data? Any idea?

Comment: `as.POSIXct(dates, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")` works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or we can use `order(as.Date())`.

```
> dt[order(as.Date(dt, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"))]
 [1] "Fri Apr 11 10:02:42 +0000 2014" "Thu Apr 02 12:42:07 +0000 2015" "Sun Apr 03 00:37:19 +0000 2016"
 [4] "Wed Apr 13 09:45:05 +0000 2016" "Thu May 18 11:26:10 +0000 2017" "Thu Oct 05 03:41:32 +0000 2017"
 [7] "Tue Jan 09 13:57:33 +0000 2018" "Sat Apr 14 03:08:30 +0000 2018" "Thu Apr 19 00:42:24 +0000 2018"
[10] "Wed Apr 25 02:24:49 +0000 2018"
```

***Data***

```
dt <- c("Thu Apr 19 00:42:24 +0000 2018", "Sat Apr 14 03:08:30 +0000 2018" ,
        "Thu Apr 02 12:42:07 +0000 2015", "Wed Apr 25 02:24:49 +0000 2018", 
        "Sun Apr 03 00:37:19 +0000 2016", "Fri Apr 11 10:02:42 +0000 2014",
        "Tue Jan 09 13:57:33 +0000 2018" ,"Wed Apr 13 09:45:05 +0000 2016" ,
        "Thu May 18 11:26:10 +0000 2017","Thu Oct 05 03:41:32 +0000 2017")
```

Comment: dear @jaySf - this worked perfectly. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that removes the extraneous `+0000` and moves the year to be next to the month and day with a regular expression, and then uses `lubridate`'s parser to get the desired output. Probably if you prefer regular expressions to remembering `strptime` codes...

```r
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
dates <- c(
  "Thu Apr 19 00:42:24 +0000 2018", "Sat Apr 14 03:08:30 +0000 2018",
  "Thu Apr 02 12:42:07 +0000 2015", "Wed Apr 25 02:24:49 +0000 2018",
  "Sun Apr 03 00:37:19 +0000 2016", "Fri Apr 11 10:02:42 +0000 2014",
  "Tue Jan 09 13:57:33 +0000 2018", "Wed Apr 13 09:45:05 +0000 2016",
  "Thu May 18 11:26:10 +0000 2017", "Thu Oct 05 03:41:32 +0000 2017"
)

dates %>%
  str_replace_all("(^.{4})(.{6} )(.{8})( \\+0000 )(\\d{4})$", "\\2\\5 \\3") %>%
  mdy_hms()
#>  [1] "2018-04-19 00:42:24 UTC" "2018-04-14 03:08:30 UTC"
#>  [3] "2015-04-02 12:42:07 UTC" "2018-04-25 02:24:49 UTC"
#>  [5] "2016-04-03 00:37:19 UTC" "2014-04-11 10:02:42 UTC"
#>  [7] "2018-01-09 13:57:33 UTC" "2016-04-13 09:45:05 UTC"
#>  [9] "2017-05-18 11:26:10 UTC" "2017-10-05 03:41:32 UTC"
```

Created on 2018-07-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: See [my comment above (in MKR's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565905/convert-datetime-strings-and-order-by-date#comment90099061_51566062), removing `+0000` is the wrong approach.

Comment: Ah, I did not know what that information was. That makes this approach unwieldy; I don't know off the top of my head how the `tz` argument to `lubridate` parsers accept input.

Comment: Honestly, it's (experienced) speculation on my part that it is timezone. It's what numeric offset looks like in many timestamp formats (even if the order of fields in the provided strings is *inane* ... it's not even the broken-US-order!). Some offset formats use just `+00`, but this misses timezones that are not hour-aligned (e.g., Afghanistan, central Australia, ..., [shown here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/)). Other TZ formats vary from `"PST8PDT"` to `"US/Eastern"`, thereby encouraging a package like `lubridate` to help make sense of it all. (Daylight-savings is even funnier ...)